# JSF controller as a variable

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, ejb

I'm trying to create a JSF form with a JPA backend.
The class stucture relies heavily on inheritance.
I was trying to get the JSF forms to be modular so I can include diffrent parts depending on the class of the object being made. Now I stumbled on the problem that I need the controller of the subclass to set all the data. So I was looking to set the controller-identifier as a variable first then include the form piece of the superclass (and within that of the superclass above that and so on)

(the includes aren't in the code yet)

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h1><h:outputText value="Make FieldPlayer"/></h1>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <c:set var="controller" value="#{fieldPlayerController}" scope="request" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="naam" />
            <h:inputText id="naam" value="#{controller.fieldPlayer.name}" title="Naam" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Birthday:" for="prijs" />
            <h:inputText id="prijs" value="#{controller.birthday}" title="Prijs"/>
            <h:commandButton value="save" action="#{controller.add()}"></h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

But I'm getting the following error: 
/add_fieldPlayer.xhtml @17,94 value="#{controller.fieldPlayer.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'controller' resolved to null

Did I make an error somewhere? Or can't controllers be set in a variable?

Controller code:

```
@Named(value = "fieldPlayerController")
@SessionScoped
public class FieldPlayerController extends PlayerController<FieldPlayer> {

    public FieldPlayerController() {
        super(FieldPlayer.class);
    }
}

@Named(value = "playerController")
@Dependent
public abstract class PlayerController<T> implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private AbstractFacade<T> facade;
    private T player;

    public PlayerController(Class<T> entityClass) {
        try {
            this.player = entityClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public T getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(T p) {
        this.player = p;
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return this.facade.findAll();
    }

    public String add() throws ParseException {
        this.facade.create(player);
        try {
            this.player = (T) player.getClass().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "index";
    }
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post your controller code as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see: your controller *fieldPlayerController* doesn't own the property *fieldPlayer*, use *player* instead:

```
<h:inputText id="naam" value="#{controller.player.name}" title="Naam" />
```

If still the *controller* validates to null, try to use *param*:

```
<f:param name = "controller" value = "#{fieldPlayerController}" />
```

But the *param* tag does not provide a *scope* attribute ...